# Solr highlightning distinction

Tags: solr, highlighting

When I look for the word "Unternehmen" with the following query

```
q="Unternehmen"&
hl=true&
hl.simple.pre=<em>&
hl.simple.post=</em>
```

I get this Result if the Word Unternehmen is found twice within a close distance within the same field:

Um als **`<em>Unternehmen die Zukunft erfolgreich zu gestalten, brauchen Unternehmen</em>`** Innovationen

When "Unternehmen" is found within the same field not within close distance solr gives me:

olle in **`<em>Unternehmen</em>`**, hat eine lange Tradition in der Betriebswirtschaftslehre. Dieses Special Issue widmet sich in vielfältiger Weise dem Thema der geeigneten Corporate Governance in mittelständischen oder öffentlichen deutschen **`<em> Unternehmen </em>`**. ​

How do I prevent solr from merging highlighting when the matches are too close? I always want to get the second variation of highlighting.

I already tried playing around with `hl.fragsize=` 0, 10,1000,  `hl.snippets=2` with no visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example in Solr 5 here using the standard /select Request Handler, and highlighting worked as expected (your second variation) on the first sentence.

Try the following:

1. What field type do you have for the field where you are querying and highlighting text in? Even if it is German, try "text_en" as the field type and re-index the document for testing.
2. Try querying and highlighting not on the general catch-all field, but specifically on the field (lets assume it is "mytext") you have your text, such as:

   ```
   q=mytext:"Unternehmen"&hl=true&hl.fl=mytext&hl.simple.pre=<em>&hl.simple.post=</em>
   ```